# Opencart3 debug

Tags: php, отладка, opencart3.x

Всем доброго дня. как в настройках OC-3 включить дебаг,чтобы мониторить запросы и сессионные переменные?

Пробовал инструкцию:

Opencart3 is using template engine Twig. By default, debug mode is disabled. Is very simple to enable it - in the file system/library/template/Twig/Environment.php param 'debug' turn to true and add the string below

```
$this->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
```

[Нажмите и перетащите, чтобы переместить]

Now, you can use constructions like this in templates:

```
{{ debug(var) }}
```

Но бьет ошибку

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'Unknown "debug" function in "default/template/extension/quickcheckout/checkout.twig" at line 182.' in D:\open_server\OpenServer\domains\OC-Shop\system\library\template\Twig\ExpressionParser.php:574 Stack trace: #0 D:\open_server\OpenServer\domains\OC-Shop\system\library\template\Twig\ExpressionParser.php(351): Twig_ExpressionParser->getFunctionNodeClass('debug', 182) #1 D:\open_server\OpenServer\domains\OC-Shop\system\library\template\Twig\ExpressionParser.php(144): Twig_ExpressionParser->getFunctionNode('debug', 182) #2 D:\open_server\OpenServer\domains\OC-Shop\system\library\template\Twig\ExpressionParser.php(84): Twig_ExpressionParser->parsePrimaryExpression() #3 D:\open_server\OpenServer\domains\OC-Shop\system\library\template\Twig\ExpressionParser.php(41): Twig_ExpressionParser->getPrimary() #4 D:\open_server\OpenServer\domains\OC-Shop\system\library\template\Twig\Parser.php(144): Twig_ExpressionParser->parseExpression() #5 D:\open_server\OpenServer\do in D:\open_server\OpenServer\domains\OC-Shop\system\library\template\Twig\ExpressionParser.php on line 574
```

Comment: Почему не используете xdebug?

Comment: не знал о нем, сейчас буду разбираться